# How to change color of Ellipse when pressing a button on Kivy?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I am stuck on how to change the color of some ellipse elements dynamically; I put all generated points into a list. Then I want to change their color:

In fact, using params to change is seems not to be a good idea for that

```
from random import random
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse, Line

points = []

class MyPaintWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            self.size= [50,50]
            self.pos = [100,50]
            self.r = 0
            super(MyPaintWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        color = (self.r, 1, 1)
        with self.canvas:
            Color(*color, mode='hsv')
            d = 30.
            pts = Ellipse(pos=(touch.x - d / 2, touch.y - d / 2), size=(d, d))
            points.append(pts)

class MyPaintApp(App):

    def build(self):
        parent = Widget()
        self.painter = MyPaintWidget()
        clearbtn = Button(text='Change Color')
        clearbtn.bind(on_release=self.change_color)
        parent.add_widget(self.painter)
        parent.add_widget(clearbtn)
        return parent

    def change_color(self, obj):
        print(len(points))
        points[0].r = 0.2 <= Error !
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `on_touch_down()` method is adding graphics instructions to the canvas with every touch. In order to change the color of all the `Ellipses`, you would need to change each of those `Color` commands. That could be done, but a simpler approach is to just to clear the canvas, and add new graphics instructions to redraw all the `Ellipses` with the new color. Here is a modified version of your code that does that:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse


class MyPaintWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyPaintWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size= [50,50]
        self.pos = [100,50]
        self.d = 30
        self.r = 0          # the hue
        self.ellipses = []  # a list of points for the Ellipses

    def redraw(self):
        # method to clear the canvas and redraw all the Ellipses with new hue
        self.canvas.clear()
        with self.canvas:
            Color(self.r, 1, 1, mode='hsv')
            for pt in self.ellipses:
                Ellipse(pos=pt, size=(self.d,self.d))

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        # just add a new position to the list and redraw
        self.ellipses.append((touch.x - self.d / 2, touch.y - self.d / 2))
        self.redraw()


class MyPaintApp(App):
    def build(self):
        parent = Widget()
        self.painter = MyPaintWidget()
        clearbtn = Button(text='Change Color')
        clearbtn.bind(on_release=self.change_color)
        parent.add_widget(self.painter)
        parent.add_widget(clearbtn)
        return parent

    def change_color(self, obj):
        print(len(self.painter.ellipses))
        self.painter.r = 0.2  # change the hue
        self.painter.redraw() # and redraw


MyPaintApp().run()
```